# Trigger argo workflow template via argo events based on webhook payload data key

Tags: argo-events

im  looking for a way to trigger a workflow using webhook json payload key for example
if payload is {"action":"copy","id":"someid"}

on  triggers

```
triggers:
   template:
    - "group1"
      "use this template if action key is 'copy'"
    - "group2"
      "use this template" if action key is 'move'"
```

i have created a example sensor file but, argo sersor is complaining that eventSourceName used multiple times.

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Sensor
metadata:
  name: testing-sensor
spec:
  template:
    serviceAccountName: argo 
  dependencies:
    - name: data
      eventSourceName: testhook
      eventName: test
      filters:
        data:
          - path: body.message
            type: string
            value:
              - copy
    
    - name: data1
      eventSourceName: testhook
      eventName: test
      filters:
        data:
          - path: body.message
            type: string
            value:
              - move
  triggers:
    - template:
        conditions: "data"
        name: group-1
        
    - template:
        conditions: "data1"
        name: group-2
```

If some one could help it would be nice

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [data filter](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-events/tutorials/07-filters/) in your Sensor. ([Example sensor](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-events/blob/master/examples/tutorials/07-filters/sensor-data-filters.yaml#L12).)

It would look something like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Sensor
metadata:
  name: data-filter
spec:
  dependencies:
    - name: test-dep
      eventSourceName: webhook
      eventName: example
      filters:
        data:
          - path: body.action
            type: string
            value:
              - "copy"
  triggers:
    - template:
        name: data-workflow
        k8s:
          group: argoproj.io
          version: v1alpha1
          resource: workflows
          operation: create
# ...
```

Comment: Thanks @Micheal for reply  i  have updated my question could you help me on this, i have checked argo sensor example but i couldnt find anything about this scenario.